# SQL View of TABLE and with record for conditions COUNT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-view

I'm trying to create a VIEW for a specific query as following.

4 Tables

```
1. users(user_id, name, profilepic)
2. topics (topic_id, topic_by_id, topic_title, topic_data, timestamp)
3. likes (topic_id, liked_by_id, timestamp)
4. comments (topic_id, comment_by_id, comment_text, timestamp)
```

Now I've created a view for the first two tables to get the data. But next step is to get the number of likes and number of comments and see if the current user has liked or commented on this topic.

`topics` Table is the main table here, `topic_by_id` is the `user_id` in `users` table and `liked_by_id` and `comment_by_id` is also `user_id`.

This is what i've done so far to achieve the initial data from first two tables.

```
CREATE VIEW TOPICS_VIEW AS 
SELECT topic.topic_id,
topic.topic_by_id AS TBYID,
topic.topic_title,
users.user_id AS UserID,
users.name, 
users.profiepic
FROM users,topic
WHERE user.user_id = topic.topic_by_id
```

Now how can I edit this query to include the number of likes and comments and check if the user have liked or commented on the same topic?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Learn to use `JOIN` and `ON`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, yes I've started with JOIN but can't figure out how to use it here in this case exactly. If you can help?

Comment: @user4628469: so you want to know how many likes and comments each topic had. But what to you mean by: *check if the user have liked or commented on the same topic*?

Comment: @GMB, it is to show a Liked and/or Commented icon next to the topic in the UsersFeed page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT posts.post_id,
posts.post_creator_id AS Post_by_id,
users.user_id AS UserID,
users.f_name, 
users.profile_pic_url,
posts.post_title,
posts.post_text,
posts.post_image,
posts.post_location,
posts.post_timestamp,
posts.post_category,
posts.post_status,
(SELECT count(*) FROM post_likes WHERE users.user_id = post_likes.liked_user_id) as 
User_Liked,
(SELECT count(*) FROM post_comments WHERE users.user_id = 
post_comments.comment_creater_id) as User_Commented,
(SELECT count(*) FROM post_likes WHERE posts.post_id = post_likes.liked_post_id) as 
Total_Likes_On_Post,
(SELECT count(*) FROM post_comments WHERE posts.post_id = 
post_comments.comment_post_id) as Total_Comments_On_Post
FROM users,posts
WHERE users.user_id = posts.post_creator_id
```